# Best way to export a large dataframe to a single file that can be consumed by Power BI

Tags: pyspark, powerbi, azure-databricks

I'm processing a large number of input files in Azure Databricks. My final dataframe has approximately 98million rows.

I need to export this out from Databricks so that I can import it to Power BI for reporting.

Power BI does not currently seem to have a connector that can interpret the partitioned nature if I simply write the dataframe to e.g. CSV.  Making use of coalesce or converting to a pandas dataframe and exporting to CSV is very slow and prone to resource limitations on the cluster.

I've tried both of the above approaches with little success.

What other options do I have to efficiently export my dataframe in a way that Power BI can understand?  I don't mind if this is either from the Databricks side or the Power Query side of the processing.

Comment: Hello, can you export your data frame from data bricks to sql server or azure sql database and just pull the data from there?

Comment: That seems like a long winded way to do things.  I was hoping that there would be some logical way to do this.   The annoying thing is that the examples of importing "big" data from a Data Lake always seems to show it in nice ordered folder structures with a single file at the leaf level - either unrealistic examples or I'm missing a trick.

Comment: Maybe a bit of marketing 'Magic' lol sorry I've never worked with data bricks. Just thought I'd throw in my .02

Answer (score 0):

PowerBI has an existing connector for databricks. We take our CSV data and convert it into a databricks delta formatted table that is partitioned. We have billions of records in ours and PowerBI is able to pull it up fine.

Make sure you follow the steps here to connect your PowerBI to databricks cluster:
https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/bi/power-bi.html#connect-power-bi-desktop-to-a-databricks-cluster